# IF statement sending multiple results

Tags: arrays, powershell, if-statement

I have a PowerShell script that cycles through AD and sends emails to users that have passwords expiring in 14, 7, and 3 days. Some individuals it behaves normally and other times it will send several emails to the same individual.

```
#Set Global Variables
$sender = "email@xyz.com"
$MailSubject = "Domain/VPN/Office 365: Password Expiring Notification!" 
$maxPasswordAge = '90'


#Run the command to get information from Active Directory
$CommandToGetInfoFromAD = Get-ADUser -filter * -properties PasswordLastSet, PasswordExpired, PasswordNeverExpires, EmailAddress, GivenName, mail

#Loop through all users and compare dates.
$CommandToGetInfoFromAD | ForEach {
    $Today = (Get-Date)
    $UserName = $_.GivenName
    $email = $_.mail
    if (!$_.PasswordExpired -and !$_.PasswordNeverExpires) {
        $ExpiryDate = ($_.PasswordLastSet+$maxPasswordAge)
        $ExpiryDateForEmail = $ExpiryDate.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd yyyy a\t hh:mm tt")
        $DaysLeft = ($ExpiryDate-$Today).days


$props = @{
SMTPServer = "relay.xyz"
From = $sender
To = $email
Subject = $MailSubject
}

$body = @"
<p>$UserName,</p>
<p>This is a courtesy reminder that your Domain password is set to expire on $ExpiryDateForEmail.<br>
<br>
#body removed
"@

}


if ($DaysLeft -eq 14) {
    
    Send-MailMessage @props -body $body -BodyAsHtml -verbose
    }

  elseif ($DaysLeft -eq 7) {
  
    Send-MailMessage @props -body $body -BodyAsHtml -verbose
}

  elseif ($DaysLeft -eq 3) {

    Send-MailMessage @props -body $body -BodyAsHtml -Verbose
}
  
}
```

It should only send it once to each user per day. It runs as a scheduled task once a day. Some days it works fine and other days/users it will send 35+ emails.

Comment: Are you sure CommandToGetInfoFromAD  only returns each person once ?

Comment: The code above only has one for loop.  So only way more than one can be sent is if Get-ADUser contains more than one record for each user.  Since Get-ADUser doesn't have more than one entry for each user the issue must be with the schedule task.  When a user gets multiple records what are the times of the multiple emails?  Are the times very close together or far apart?

Comment: In message trace they all show as sent at the exact same time or at least very close. I did pull the get command out separately and ran it to a CSV. It is only pulling a single record for each user.

Comment: Create a hash table of IDs, if email sent add to hash table. If in hash table, don't send.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is, but I’d suggest replacing the multiple ```$DaysLeft -eq …``` with a single ```if ($DaysLeft -in @( 3, 7, 14 ) )``` as a starter, and then add some logging to output the parameters to each call to ```Send-MailMessage``` and verify your assumptions about what it’s actually doing. Review the logs after running and then add more logging around areas that don’t give the expected output…

Comment: For example, perhaps the ```mail``` AD attribute contains *multiple* email addresses for the same user on different corporate email domains and ```Send-MailMessage``` is sending a message to every address but they all get routed to the same back-end mailbox - if you log the parameters you’d see this very quickly when you review the logs…

Answer (score 0):

Your code could do with better indentation so it is easier to spot where things may go wrong.

Also, I would create the body template Here-string using placeholders `{0}` and `{1}` where later the users GivenName and the expirydate are inserted.
Create the `$props` splatting hashtable only there where you are sure you are going to use it.

Try:

```
# Set Global Variables
$sender         = 'email@xyz.com'
$smtpServer     = 'relay.xyz'
$MailSubject    = 'Domain/VPN/Office 365: Password Expiring Notification!'
$maxPasswordAge = 90  # an integer value, so no quotes here

# use a Here-string for the body with two placeholders
$body = @'
<p>{0},</p>
<p>This is a courtesy reminder that your Domain password is set to expire on {1}.<br>
<br>
#body removed
'@

# Run the command to get information from Active Directory
# property GivenName is automatically returned, same as DistinguishedName, Enabled, Name, ObjectClass, 
# ObjectGUID, SamAccountName, SID, Surname and UserPrincipalName
$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -properties PasswordLastSet, PasswordExpired, PasswordNeverExpires, EmailAddress

# Loop through all users and compare dates.
$users | ForEach-Object {
    if (!$_.PasswordExpired -and !$_.PasswordNeverExpires) {
        $Today      = (Get-Date)
        $ExpiryDate = $_.PasswordLastSet.AddDays($maxPasswordAge)
        $DaysLeft   = ($ExpiryDate - $Today).Days
        # only send an email if the number of days left is 14, 7 or 3
        if (3,7,14 -contains $DaysLeft) {  
            $props = @{
                SMTPServer = $smtpServer
                From       = $sender
                To         = $_.EmailAddress
                Subject    = $MailSubject
                Body       = $body -f $_.GivenName, $ExpiryDate.ToString("dddd, MMMM dd yyyy a\t hh:mm tt")
                BodyAsHtml = $true
            }
            Send-MailMessage @props -Verbose
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using the `mail` or `EmailAddress` property of the user, you could also get the primary emailaddress from the users `ProxyAddresses` attribute
First append `ProxyAddresses` to the list of properties you want to fetch with Get-ADUser, then in the `$props` set the To address like this:

```
To = ($_.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object { $_ -clike 'SMTP:*' }) -creplace '^SMTP:'  
# all-caps SMTP: is the primary email address
```